# Make [rg] a synonym of [ripgrep]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

While the actual amount of [ripgrep](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ripgrep)/[rg](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rg) questions is currently rather low (1 exlusive [rg](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rg), 1 exclusive [ripgrep](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ripgrep), 1 tagged with both), we should probably nip the usage of both in the bud and make one of them a synonym of the other.

There [are currently ~6 questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=ripgrep+is%3Aquestion) containing `ripgrep`, and [~16 containing `rg`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=rg%20is%3Aquestion), some of them use [grep](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grep) instead of [rg](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rg) or [ripgrep](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ripgrep) or the tag of the completion framework (counsel, helm, ivy, ...).

Unfortunately, I lack the necessary reputation to suggest a synonym myself. I've [suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18655) an initial excerpt for [ripgrep](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ripgrep) and propose that we make [rg](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rg) a synonym of [ripgrep](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ripgrep). I suggest [rg](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rg) as the synomym, as `rg` is the name of the binary, where as [ripgrep](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ripgrep) is the name of the project.

Comment: +1. Sounds reasonable to me. Dunno how such things get decided/done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.  I've merged `rg` into `ripgrep` and made it a synonym.